# Static Block Not showing up on left sidebar of CMS pages

Tags: cms, static-block, sidebar

1).
I am having problem in displaying Static Block on CMS pages Left Sidebar.

My Settings: CMS Page -> Design -> Layout -> 2 columns with left bar

Layout Update XML:

```
<reference name="left"> <block type="cms/block"
name="left.permanent.callout"> <action
method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_menu</block_id></action> </block>
</reference>
```

On CMS pages there is left block however nothing shows up (empty left bar)

Anyone who could help?

Thank you

**PS:** Yes I have created left_menu under static blocks

Comment: clear the cache and then try again and make sure static block is enabled

Comment: Yes, I have checked it many times, static blocked Enabled and cache cleared several times. This was working fine with custom theme since I switched to default rwd theme, left block on cms pages stopped working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem you have is the name of the block you are trying to insert.
In the Magento rwd theme in the cms.xml layout file the block with that name is remove from the layout:

`<remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>`

Try changing the name from left.permanent.callout to something else and it should work.

Comment: Brilliant! I removed the above from cms.xml Many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!